# How to get all related objects in django model ForeignKey and OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-select-related

I'm using django 1.9.
I have the following Django models:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Projects(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=1)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  '%s, %s, %s, %s' %(self.index,self.year,self.title,
               self.description)
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Awards(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %( self.title)


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Images(models.Model):
    projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects,null=True,blank=True, related_name='images_projects')
    awards =  models.OneToOneField(Awards,null=True,blank=True,related_name='images_awards')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload_images/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' %(self.file, self.pk)
```

1)I'm trying to get all the model objects Projects and model objects Images that are related to the model Projects    `Projects.objects.all().select_related('images_projects')`
As a result, I get only model objects Projects.

2) I want to get all the objects of the model Awards and associated fields in the Images.

```
 Awards.objects.all().prefetch_related('images_awards')
```

As a result, I receive only all fields of the Award model.

How to get related fields together with all objects of the main model in my 2 cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) are **performance boosters** that retrieve the related objects for the *current lookup*. The query returns the corresponding objects (primarily) for the lookup, and then the related objects are fetched alongside;

You still need to use the regular syntax for accessing the related object in Python.

e.g.

```
for p in Projects.objects.all().select_related('images_projects'):
    print(p.images_projects)
```

No database trips will be made for accessing `p.images_projects` since it was already fetched alongside the `project`.

Comment: Thanks! You really helped!